# How can I check my computer manufacturer

Tags: bios

I must know the company that produced my PC in order to download proper bios
installer to reinstall it. On the computer case there is only written "komputronik" which is my country's vendor (there's a little chance it produced the machine) and "chieftec" which is manufacturer of cases.
I also don't have any knowledge about it from while purchasing.

Comment: Usually doing `sudo dmidecode -t 1` or try changing the `1` to `2` or `3` might give you the info you need about the motherboard in your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo lshw -html > /tmp/info.html
```

and then open that html inside a browser with ...

```
firefox /tmp/info.html
```

Example from my machine:

[image]